# Setting an image above of a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Iam currently working on a iPad project where i build my code on top of the premade "Split View-based Application".
I am trying to place a image above of the UITableViewController when i rotate my iPad into landscape mode, however i do not know if it is possible without having the image appear in the popover-menu when displaying in portrait mode. 
I can't place a UIImageView inside IB, so trying to do it from the code.

Here is a image of my table: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSpC5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and position the image programaticaly when initializing the view, and implement the following method in the view controller:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
        imageOverTableview.hidden = !UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);

        return YES;
    }
```